# Getting the events from EventStore

Tags: c#, cqrs, neventstore

If I want to fill a new Viewmodel based on all historical events stored in the ES how would I do that?

I can see the `IPersistStreams.GetFrom(DateTime)` but it seems a bit scary to get them all in one go.

I'm thinking that fetching them in batches is what I'm looking for.

EventStore 3.0 is the one I'm using.

Comment: How many events are we looking at?

Answer (score 4):

Under the hood, it's not "all in one go".  The EventStore is smart enough to page through the results on your behalf so that you're not loading hundreds of thousands or even millions of events into memory.  You can even configure the paging size during EventStore wireup.

Comment: That is great, figured I wasn't the first thinking about this. So if I use paging GetFrom() will return that number of commits and then I will use the timestamp of the last in the next go?